# Проголосовать за вопрос с ответом, за который вы проголосовали против?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги

На нашем сайте вопросов и ответов часто встречаю фразы вида:

> Проголосовал *за* вопрос против.

Обычно я изменяю эту фразу на:

> Проголосовал *в* вопросе против.

Которая, на самом деле, тоже несколько не верна: мы голосуем за/против вопроса, а в вопрос за или против ответов.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно описать голос за или против вопроса или ответа?

Реальная фраза для задания контекста:

> Вы отметили тревогой неправильный ответ, за который вы просто могли проголосовать против или отредактировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, можно говорить так:

> Я проголосовал против вопроса.

или

> Я проголосовал за вопрос.

Применительно к приведенной фразе:

> Вы отметили тревогой неправильный ответ, **против** котор**ого** вы просто могли проголосовать или **который вы могли** отредактировать.

Но по собственному опыту могу сказать, что понятны и следующие выражения:

- Поставить +1 или -1.
- Отдать голос за (вопрос/ответ/комментарий) или отдать голосов против (вопроса/ответа).

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, есть ли правило, согласно которому фраза «за который проголосовал против» не верна? Или это вопрос стиля?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это вопрос культуры речи, тут конкретное правило найти трудно. «За который проголосовал против» вызывает в конце концов вопрос: так _за_ проголосовал или _против_? Дело в том, что есть устойчивая конструкция проголосовать _за/против_ что-л., которую и следует использовать в рассматриваемом случае. Если же после «проголосовать _за_» вставлять еще слово _против_, то а) высказывание становится нелогичным, б) «разрушается» устойчивая конструкция (голосовать за/против) -- а это стилистическая ошибка.